# Get the list of all the week days translated in dart

Tags: flutter, date, dart

I would like to get all the names of each week day translated so I can displayed them,
but I can't figure out how to do it.

I know how to get a localized week day name for a particular date with: `DateTime(...).format('E')` but that's not what I want.

Ideally I would do something like this:

```dart
var localizedWeekDays = getLocalizedWeekDays('en_US');
print(localizedWeekDays);
// ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', ...]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

in your pubspec.yaml file, dependencies section. add intl dependency

```dart
dependencies:
  intl: ^0.17.0
```

add then import the package

```dart
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
```

to get all localized weekdays

```dart
final weekdays = DateFormat().dateSymbols.WEEKDAYS;
// [Sunday, Monday, ...]
```

There are many more options available:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/date_symbols/DateSymbols-class.html